# What does `clang-check` do without `-analyze` option?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

`clang-check`, Clang's built-in static analysis tool, has an `-analyze` option, for which the help string just says "Run static analysis engine." With this flag, I see very little output from running `clang-check` on several of my files; without it, I see a lot of warnings.

Isn't running the static analysis engine the main purpose of running `clang-check`, which is a static analysis tool? Why do I see *less* output when running the engine, and what does the tool do without the flag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running `clang-check` without any options runs the `-fsyntax-only` mode (checking for correct syntax). Only if you specify `-analyze`, the static analysis tool is executed, see http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html for a full list of executed checks.

- Note 1: you can do various other stuff with clang-check, e.g. AST dumping.
- Note 2: you cannot specify `-fsyntax-only` and `-analyze` at the same time.

Comment: It sounds like `-analyze` should *always* emit *more* output, then, which does not appear to be the behavior I'm seeing...

Comment: No, it doesn't. `-analyze` does not combine `-fsyntax-only` and its own checkers.

Comment: Oh, it sounds like I misunderstood your second point, then. So `-analyze` won't emit errors for code that (according to Clang) isn't even syntactically valid?